# OSError : Initializing from file failed with pd.read(csv) since last macOS update

Tags: python, pandas, macos

I have a serious problem with one of the major function of python : `pd.read_csv`.

Before the last update of macOS, my code run perfectly. But since the last macOS update Catalina, it seems that all the time I try to lunch `pd.read_csv`, python send me this error :

> OSError Initializing from file failed.

- I checked my pathway (OK);
- I check the file (OK);
- and I check the permissions (seems to be OK).

At this point, I don't know what to do anymore.

I tried also to specify on my `pd.read_csv('filename.txt', engine='python')` but, when I try this, I have the following error :

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted.

Somebody had this error also and found a solution to this issue?

Comment: If you need more informations, let me know :)
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Loic Gc.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I don't currently work on Mac so I don't have a Mac specific answer but typically on my Linux OS's Catalina/Tomcat runs as the user tomcat which doesn't have much permission to access other files.  So I would `sudo -u tomcat -i` and then as the tomcat user try to run the python script.  If this doesn't help, then hopefully someone who has a Mac will respond to you.

Comment: So I try to run this command line on my Mac terminal but I have the following error. 
sudo: unknown user: tomcat
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
So I admit I don't get it ^^'
Also I use anaconda and Spyder to run my python program :)

Comment: I get the same error after upgrading to Catalina.  All was working fine, I havent changed anything, this was the first this I did after upgrading and I got the same error.